# what does the `exports.notEmpty` mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

the code is as following:

```js
exports.notEmpty = name => {
  return v => {
    if (!v || v.trim === '') {
      return `${name} is required`
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

and I can not find this explanation in GOOGLE,MDN...

Comment: If you need help with nodejs, you should be looking at [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut), not MDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means : if this funtion is defined in module named my-module.js , you can use this function in other modules as : const { notEmpty }= require('my-module') . Hope it helps :- )

Answer (score 0):

your are **exporting** or **exposing** function and you named it **notEmtpy** and this function takes variable and you named it **v** and check if this variable is empty or not but before that you are doing **trim** which means you are removing the spaces from this variable